# R' Frand's famous speech from the 11th Siyum Hashas

Tags: sources-mekorot, adult-learning, siyum, shas

R' Yissocher Frand gave a famous speech at the 11th Siyum Hashas. He kept repeating the phrase, "it's never too little, it's never too late, it's never enough." Afterwards, he made it into a book.

I want to see the video of his speech, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Does anyone know where I can obtain a copy of the shiur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video of the 11th Siyum Hashas can be found [here](https://vimeo.com/537367605/description). As you said, the specific quote may be found at 18:07.